# WPF - Nested Listbox Binding Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I am working on a project which has a nested `listbox`. The `ItemsSource` of inner-listbox referring to a `collection of string` defined in its parent listbox's ItemsSource.  But when I run the code, *I can't able to see the binded data in the nested listbox*.

I searched the forum and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187130/wpf-nested-listview-itemssource?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896198/c-sharp-wpf-listview-binding-not-working?rq=1) solution but I wasn't able to resolve the problem yet. Maybe there is a problem with the code. So here is how the code looks like:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Name="detailList" Margin="5,5,0,0">

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="90" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="60" Height="30" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="11" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                <Expander Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" DockPanel.Dock="Top">

                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubFamiliesNames}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                               <StackPanel>
                                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                               </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

                </Expander>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public ObservableCollection<DirectoryItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
public DefaultControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Items = new ObservableCollection<DirectoryItemViewModel>
    {
        /*Some Initial Data*/
    };
    this.DataContext = Items;
}
```

---

**DirectoryItemViewModel.cs**

```
public class DirectoryItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    // Constructor
    public DirectoryItemViewModel()
    {            
        //initialize some data          

        _subfamiliesnames = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        _subfamiliesnames.Add("File1");
        _subfamiliesnames.Add("File2");
        _subfamiliesnames.Add("File3");

    }

    #region Public Properties

    public ObservableCollection<string> _subfamiliesnames;        
    public ObservableCollection<string> SubFamiliesNames
    {
        get { return _subfamiliesnames; }
        set
        {
            _subfamiliesnames = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SubFamiliesNames");
        }
    }

    // Full path of the directory
    public string FullPath { get; set; }

    // Item type (Enum)
    public DirectoryItemType Type { get; set; }  

    public string Visibility
    {
        get
        { 
           return "Visible";               
        }
    }

    //The name of the Directory
    public string Name { get { return this.Type == DirectoryItemType.Drive ? this.FullPath : DirectoryStructure.GetFileFolderName(FullPath); } }

    #endregion

}
```

Please share your solutions, would really appreciate the support. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't make a huge amount of sense to nest listboxes this way - I would look again at what the idea presentation for the UI you want to achieve is? Typically, a tree is more appropriate for hierarchical data.

Comment: @AdamBrown as per my use-case, I can't use a tree to represent data. Therefore, nested listbox is a way forward. But I'm struggling in data-binding. Please, can you look at this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code behind, the data context is specified as Items.
So for the ItemSource of the detailList, it will try to find the occurrence of Items, within the Items collection.

Try specifying, *this.DataContext = this;* in the code behind.
It will then try to find 'Items' in DefaultControl class and will be successfully able to locate it.

Do let me know in case it still does not show the required data in your listview.

[After modified code, the listbox shows data like following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7g5S.png)

Comment: DataContext = this; is considered very bad practice in controls, because it breaks all bindings from the parent.

Comment: I tried but It didn't work either...can you suggest any other workaround, please?

Comment: Its all about finding the item which you are binding. In case your ItemSource exists in codebehind, you need to do this. For better practice, you can create another viewmodel and move Items to that viewmodel and set datacontext to newly created viewmodel. Answer is based on the code of the one who is posting it.

Comment: interesting, your explanation has shed some light. will try the solution again. Thanks

Comment: I've checked the screenshot, just one question, can you share the xaml with me? I'd like to know how you are handling the nested listbox binding. Thanks

Comment: I used your xaml only. The working solution can be fetched from here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hOEq6HiPp3FzCYzeunuFeeFbPHt9Th3k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do not set the DataContext at all. Neither `this.DataContext = Items;` nor `this.DataContext = this;` Both is wrong. The DataContext should be inherited from the parent element of DefaultControl, i.e. the Window where it is used.